# While I am using cv2.goodFeaturesToTrack in python with mask, the following error occure

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing

here are my code:

```
frame_gray = cv2.cvtColor(cv2.imread('image.jpg'), cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
edge_mask = np.ones((457, 702))
cv2.rectangle(edge_mask, (15, 15), (687, 442), 0, cv2.FILLED)
p_add = cv2.goodFeaturesToTrack(frame_gray, mask=edge_mask, maxCorners=50, qualityLevel=0.3, minDistance=5, blockSize=7)
```

Here is the error:

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (_mask.empty() || (_mask.type() == (((0) & ((1 << 3) - 1)) + (((1)-1) << 3)) && _mask.sameSize(_image))) in goodFeaturesToTrack, file /Users/travis/build/skvark/opencv-python/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/featureselect.cpp, line 366
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "test.py", line 59, in <module>
frame_gray, mask=edge_mask, maxCorners=50, qualityLevel=0.3, minDistance=5, blockSize=7)
cv2.error: /Users/travis/build/skvark/opencv-python/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/featureselect.cpp:366: error: (-215) _mask.empty() || (_mask.type() == (((0) & ((1 << 3) - 1)) + (((1)-1) << 3)) && _mask.sameSize(_image)) in function goodFeaturesToTrack
```

Both the frame_gray and edge_mask have the shape of (457, 702) and because I don't understand the "(((0) & ((1 << 3) - 1)) + (((1)-1) << 3))" stuff so I have no idea what is going wrong

Comment: Try using np.uint8 as your type for edge_mask.

Comment: Well, that works! Thank you for that

Answer (score 0):

`edge_mask = np.ones((457, 702))`, needs to be of datatype `uin8`

try this one:

```
edge_mask = np.ones((457, 702), dtype=np.uint8)
```